# What is the best way to store a mass amount of image for a google-app-engine?

Tags: database, image, web-services, google-app-engine, web

I want to build a personal website to upload some of my pictures.
So far I have a static folder and a direct link using HTML to pull out the picture.Example :

Let's say I have more than 3 TB of pictures ( 3 million JPEG ~ 300 KB each). How can I make this more scaleable? Assume I have 1000 users request every hour, what is the most affordable and fastest way for them to access those picture?

Comment: Have a look at the Appengine Images Python API with the ability to manipulate images and use the fast and low-cost serving_url. Google will serve the images for you. More here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App engine service built specifically for this: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/

You could also [serve them directly out of a Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). Your cost would then be per Gigabyte per month: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/